# Gmail Spam/Phishy classification not recognized by mail.app

Tags: mail.app, gmail, spam

I am running into an undesired scenario where incoming mail on gmail web interface is properly categorized as spam/phishing, however if the user employs any mail client (ie mail.app, outlook) - the same message categorization is not applied.

Specifically, mail.app and outlook running on macOS 10.14 don’t detect these known bad mails.

In hopes of curbing this, I was hoping to have gmail add custom headers to junk categorized mail, such that I depend on macOS on mail clients level spam detection will trigger and block these messages. I would like Mac mail clients to not leave these messages in the inbox.

I have tried configuring a default routing rule on Gmail to add 'x-gm-spam' and 'x-gm-phishy' headers for downstream mail servers. I still do not see these inserted.

Can someone please let me know if you know a workaround to protect users who dont use the http gmail client from spam?

Comment: This sounds like a Google/Gmail issue and not one related to Apple Mail.   It might be advisable to look into a paid service to filter spam and whatnot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](https://Apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). At present, your question really does appear to be off-topic for this site.You may want to take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if your question is off-topic, you may be able to ask it at one of our [sister sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name).

Comment: I’m going to clear the close votes. This clearly says they want to know how mail.app processes mail headers. It could be on topic for several other sites, but it’s clearly on topic here. The only reason I’d migrate it is if the OP askes for a specific site and they agree it’s on topic.

Comment: @bmike - the OP, in the first para. mentioned “any mail client” then in the second para. says would like to “have gmail add custom headers.”   It was this reason that I nominated to close as off topic

Comment: @Allan thanks, it’s very not great on detail. Would be better if it said outlook for iOS or outlook for Mac and same for mail. In the end, I still think we could put up an answer that’s totally on topic. Let me propose an edit that hopefully clarifies the OP has on scope question.